# Algorithm for combine element from an array

Tags: algorithm

I'm student and I have just completed a coding contest, I got this task, and I can't solve it on time. But I'm excited about learning how to settle this task. So, I hope you will help me deal with this.
The following section is the description of the task:

> **Short description:**
>   Two alphabets A and B.
>   An item is defined as (a, b) where a is an element of A and b is an
>   element of B.
>
> Given a set of n items, the problem is to decide whether it is able to
>   split the n items into disjoint sets (union of
>   disjoints is the original set) and the cardinality of each disjoint is
>   at least k.

The deck of cards has 52 cards: 13 cards from Ace to King (stand for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 respectively) combined with four suits Diamond, Heart, Spade and Club (stand for D, H, S, C respectively).
A card can be encoded by a string of numbers and suits, for example K Spade is represented by the string 13S, Q Diamond is represented by 12D, Ace of Club is represented by the string 1C.
A "deck" is combined from at least 3 cards and follow one of two rules below:

- They have the same number (Ex: `["1D", "1H", "1S"]` or `["2D", "2H", "2S", "2C"]`)
- They have the same suit and form a sequence of increasing numbers (Ex: `["4H", "5H", "6H", "7H",...]` or `["11S", "12S", "13S"]`)

Every player will receive 9 cards. And they have to combine their cards into "deck". They will get "perfect" status if they can combine all their cards. Ex:

- With the input `["2D", "2H", "2S", "3D", "3H", "3S", "4D", "4H", "4S"]`, they can be combined into 3 decks: `["2D", "2H", "2S"]`, `["3D", "3H", "3S"]`, `["4D", "4H", "4S"]` and the players get "perfect" status because they use all their cards.
- With the input `["2D", "2H", "2S", "3D", "3H", "3T", "4D", "5D", "6C"]`, they can be combined into 2 decks: `["2D", "2H", "2S"]`, `["3D", "3H", "3T"]` and the players can't get "perfect" status because `"4D"`, `"5D"` and `"6C"` cannot make a "deck" and their suit is different (D != C).

**Input:** A array contain 9 string represent for 9 cards. 9 strings is different and no numbers are greater than 14 or less than 1, no characters are different from D, H, S, C

**Output:** Can that 9 card able to has "perfect" status? If yes, return true, and no, return false

**Languague used:** Any. Can you use Python, Javascript, C#, Java, C/C++ because I know those languages.

Thank you for reading and sorry for my bad english

Edit: 
I coded this, but I thought It's so ugly and hard to read.

```
function isAblePerfect(playerCards) {
    var groupByNum = {};
    var groupBySuit = {};
    playerCards.forEach(card => {
        groupByNum[card.slice(0, -1)] = groupByNum[card.slice(0, -1)] || [];
        groupByNum[card.slice(0, -1)].push(card);
        groupBySuit[card[card.length - 1]] = groupBySuit[card[card.length - 1]] || [];
        groupBySuit[card[card.length - 1]].push(card);
    });
    if (Object.keys(groupByNum).every(x => groupByNum[x].length >= 3)){
        return true;
    }
    let has4Q = Object.keys(groupByNum).filter(x => groupByNum[x].length == 4).map(x => groupByNum[x]);
    if (has4Q.length == 2){
        var item = Object.keys(groupByNum).filter(x => groupByNum[x].length == 1).map(x => groupByNum[x])[0][0];
        let suit = item[item.length - 1];
        let arr = has4Q.map(x => x.find(y => y[y.length - 1] == suit));
        arr.push(item);
        arr = arr.sort((a, b) => +a.slice(0, -1) - +b.slice(0, -1));
        if (isADeck(arr)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (has4Q.length == 1){
        var cardSgl = Object.keys(groupByNum).filter(x => groupByNum[x].length == 1).map(x => groupByNum[x][0]);
        if (cardSgl.length == 2){
            if (cardSgl[0][cardSgl[0].length - 1] == cardSgl[1][cardSgl[1].length - 1]){
                let suit = cardSgl[0][cardSgl[0].length - 1];
                let cardneed = has4Q[0].find(x => x[x.length - 1] == suit);
                cardSgl.push(cardneed);
                cardSgl = cardSgl.sort((a, b) => +a.slice(0, -1) - +b.slice(0, -1));
                if (isADeck(cardSgl)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Object.keys(groupBySuit).forEach(key => {
        groupBySuit[key] = groupBySuit[key].sort((a, b) => +a.slice(0, -1) - +b.slice(0, -1));
    });
    var value = Object.keys(groupBySuit).every(key => groupBySuit[key].length >= 3 && isADeck(groupBySuit[key]));
    if (value){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        let suit4 = Object.keys(groupBySuit).map(key => groupBySuit[key]).filter(x => x.length == 4);
        if (suit4.length != 2) {
            return false;
        }
        let checkS = Object.keys(groupBySuit).map(key => groupBySuit[key]).filter(x => x.length == 1);
        let suit1 = checkS[0][0];
        let num = suit1.slice(0, -1);
        let newO = suit4.map(x => x.find(y => y.slice(0, -1) == num));
        if (newO[0] == undefined || newO[1] == undefined){
            return false;
        }
        newO.push(suit1);
        if (newO.every(x => x.slice(0, -1) == num)){
            for (let i = 0; i < suit4.length; i++){
                suit4[i] = suit4[i].filter(x => x.slice(0, -1) != num);
            }
            if (isADeck(suit4[0]) && isADeck(suit4[1])){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
function isADeck(arr){   
    if (arr.map(x => x[x.length - 1]).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).length > 1){
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (+arr[0].slice(0, -1) + i != +arr[i].slice(0, -1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I passed those testcase:
`["2D", "2S", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "4D", "4S", "4C"]` => true
`["2D", "2S", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "4D", "4S", "5H"]` => false
`["2D", "2S", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "1D", "4D", "1C"]` => false
`["2D", "2S", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "1D", "4D", "1H"]` => false
`["2D", "2S", "3D", "3S", "4D", "4S", "5D", "5S", "6H"]` => false
`["2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "10D", "11D", "12D", "13D", "9D"]` => true
`["2S", "2D", "2H", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "3H", "1S"]` => true
`["2S", "2D", "2H", "2C", "3D", "3S", "3C", "3H", "4C"]` => true
`["4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "11S", "12C"]` => false
`["4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "11S", "12S"]` => true
`["4S", "4C", "5S", "5C", "6S", "6C", "6H", "7H", "8H"]` => true
`["13S", "13D", "13H", "13C", "12S", "12D", "12H", "12C", "11D"]` => true
And there are 3 testcase I can't pass, I don't know input because it's hidden.

Comment: A simple calculation for exhaustive search. Case of 2-subgroups has (3, 6), (4,5) and case of 3-subgroups has (3, 3, 3). In total C(9, 3) + C(9, 4) + C(9, 3) * C(6, 3) = 1890 trials. That's not worth to find a `better algorithm` I think

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn you mean I should user brute-force algorithm? and check there're any perfect status in those combine?

Comment: What have you done to test the program yourself?  "I don't know input" means that you have to write a thorough test set of your own.  I suspect it's a test case of "competing" potential decks, where *your* code makes an initial assumption from which it can't backtrack.  You failed to document or trace your code for us, so I'll have to leave that part up to you.

Comment: Sure, in the constraints of this problem, trying all possible combinations is not a bad approach. This problem should be extended into a larger problem of deciding whether a set can be split into n disjoints satisfy some constraints

Comment: My coding contest is look lilke codewars platform, some testcases are visible, but some of them is not. So, I don't know what is inputed of those testcase.

Comment: Right -- as developer, you have to write a thorough set of test cases of your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if an Indian Rummy hand is a winning hand - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225335/determine-if-an-indian-rummy-hand-is-a-winning-hand-java)

Comment: No, It's not my problem

Comment: Please define the difference.  You haven't traced the problem in your code for us, so I don't see where there's a difference in the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach relying on the fact that 9 cards is not a lot.
A deck implies that every card belongs to a `combo` : 3 of a kind or square, or a sequence.

One way of checking if a vector `v` is a `deck` is:

- take out the first elem `f` of `v`
- generate all possible `combos` including `f`
- for each of those `combo`, remove the involved elems from v, and recurse
- if v is not empty but no combo available, then `v` is not a `deck`
- after having recursed, if result is true, then we are a deck:

we have a deck from underlying `v` Union a `combo` (whose elems are distinct from underlying `v`)

```
function isDeck(v){
    if(v.length == 0)return true;
    let recurse = elems=>{
        let cp = v.filter(x=>!elems.includes(x));
        let yes = isDeck(cp);
        return yes;
    }
    let card = v.shift();
    let sames = v.filter(({num, family})=>num == card.num);
    if(sames.length == 2){
        let ok = recurse(sames);
        if(ok) return true;
    }else if(sames.length == 3){
        let ok = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,2],[0,1,2]].some(kchoose=>{
            let elems = kchoose.map(idx=>sames[idx]);
            let ok = recurse(elems);
            if(ok) return true;
        });
        if(ok)return true;
    }

    //look for a sequence starting by card
    let fam = v.filter(({num, family})=>family == card.family)
    let seq = [];
    //assumes v is sorted by num asc
    fam.reduce((prev, x)=>{
        if(x.num == prev+1){
            seq.push(x);
            return x.num;
        }
        return -1;
    }, card.num);
    for(let k = seq.length; k>=2; --k){
        let ok = recurse(seq.slice(0, k));
        if(ok) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function parse(v){
    return v.map(x=>{
        var family = x[x.length-1];
        var num = parseInt(x.substring(0, x.length-1));
        return {num, family}
    })
}
//call:
let deck = parse(['2C','3C','1D','1C','1F','1H']).sort((a,b)=>a.num-b.num)
console.log(isDeck(deck));//true
```